# Raw keyboard input

Tags: keyboard, usb, mouse, raw

What I would like to do is to have e.g. a spare raspberry pi with four USB keyboards attached (or four mice).

What I want is to know, not just if a key is pressed, but *which keyboard it was pressed on*, so that different keyboard's buttons can do different things. (Think macro buttons.)
Likewise if I have four mice plugged in, I want to receive raw data and to be able to distinguish which mouse moved.

Ideally I'd like to know how to do this in C.

The device with the devices plugged into it will be controlled by SSH, so there is no need for keypresses to do what they normally do.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a start. For Linux, and this will suffice for now, there are devices in /dev/input called e.g. /dev/input/event0 from which you can read. Some of these will correspond to actual input devices, and some will be virtual.

Information can be found in /sys/class/input.
For example for my USB keyboard:

```
$ cat /sys/class/input/input24/name
Logitech K360
```

Also /sys/class/input/input24/uevent has a lot of useful information.
Now to read raw input from a keyboard, you read from something like /dev/input/event0. To find out what these events are, for example for /dev/input/event0, then /sys/class/input/event0/device points to the corresponding input24 above.

Now to read, in C,

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <linux/input.h>

/*
struct input_event {
struct timeval time;
__u16 type;
__u16 code;
__s32 value;
};
*/

int main() {
  int fd = open("/dev/input/event0", O_RDONLY);
  struct input_event evt;
  while(1) {
    read(fd,&evt,sizeof(evt));
    printf("Event: type=%hd code=%hd value=%08x=%d\n",evt.type,evt.code,evt.value,evt.value);
  }
}
```

The only remaining issue I have is how to 'disconnect' a keyboard so that its events are ignored (aside from processes reading raw input). I know how to `xinput float 34` to float e.g. device 34. That that is for Xorg, not the text console on a device without X, nor f

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for keyboards. It's also resistent to unplugging/plugging-in the devices.

**save_keys.py**:

```
import keyboard
import requests
from threading import Thread
import subprocess
import time
import sys
import os



if not os.path.exists("/tmp/pressed_keys"):
    with open("/tmp/pressed_keys", 'a+') as f:
        f.write('somedevice:somekey') #this line has no sence, just creating the file

def keyPressed(keyboardEvent: keyboard.KeyboardEvent):
    key = keyboardEvent.name
    print(key)
    device = keyboardEvent.device
    print(device)
    with open("/tmp/pressed_keys", 'a+') as f:
        f.write(f"{device}:{key)

def getDevices():
  return subprocess.getoutput('ls /dev/input/by-id/')

def startNewDeviceListener():
  while True:
    print("checking devices")
    newDevices = getDevices()
    print("got devices: ",newDevices)
    if (devices != newDevices):
      print('Device changes detected, exiting')
      sys.exit(1)

    time.sleep(0.5)

keyboard.on_press(keyPressed, True)

devices = getDevices()
t = Thread(target=startNewDeviceListener)
t.start()
```

**read_keys.py**:

```
import os

pipe_path = "/tmp/pressed_keys"
pipe_fd = os.open(pipe_path, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
with os.fdopen(pipe_fd) as pipe:
pipe.read() #seek to the end of the file
while True: #read new keys
    device_key = pipe.read()
    device, key = device_key.split(':')
    print(f"got {key} key from {device} device")
```

**save_keys.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    sudo python3 save_keys.py
    sleep 1
done
```

**run.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup ./save_keys.sh < /dev/null 2>&1 > /dev/null &
python3 read_keys.py
```

And finally run everything via:

```
sudo sh run.sh
```

Comment: The remaining question is whether there's a console or Wayland equivalent to `xinput float XX` but the Python keyboard module is good to know about.